# Changing nodes direction

Tags: swift, game-physics

I have an object that drifts slowly across a screen. When it reaches the end of the screen, I want the velocity to reverse by using the location of the node, not having it "bounce" off the side of the screen using physics. I have the function formulated to do it, but can't figure out where and how to call it. I also have defined the borders. The function looks like this:

```
func missileRedirect() {

    if missile.guy.position.x == endOfScreenLeft || missile.guy.position.x == endOfScreenRight {

        velocityX = velocityX * -1
        missile.guy.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = velocityX
        println("X-Axis")
    }

    if missile.guy.position.y == topOfScreen || missile.guy.position.y == bottomOfScreen {

        velocityY = velocityY * -1
        missile.guy.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = velocityY
        println("Y-Axis")
    }
```

Comment: Call it in your update function of the SKScene

Comment: I put it in the update but it still isn't getting called.

Comment: Add a print message to confirm it is not called at all.

Comment: @Kendel that was a good tip! So it is being called its just not working. So it must me something in the function itself.

Comment: Try doing `missile.guy.position.x <= endOfScreenLeft` and same with the other functions. The guy might not be exactly at the end of the screen, so you should check to see if the guy went a little further.

Comment: @Kendel I just got it. Thanks a million!